# Change inline color on mouseover (React)

Tags: reactjs, colors, mouseover

How can I make this to change only the element that has mouseovered and not by ids? Following is my code component that changes the text color randomly from an array when mouseover.

```
class Chroma extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
}
mouse = event => {
var colorhex = [
'#7AF377', '#3498DB', '#F1C530', '#F29C29', '#8E44AD', '#4AA086', '#E74C3C', '#65CC71','#D3541B','#EB4367','#74F7D9', '#DDA8FC',
]
var el = document.getElementById('colorstext')
el.style.color = colorhex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)]
}
mouseout = event => {
var white = '#FFFFFF'
var el = document.getElementById('colorstext')
el.style.color = white
}

render() {
return (

<a
href={this.props.link}
onMouseEnter={this.mouse}
onMouseLeave={this.mouseout}
id="colorstext"
>
{this.props.text}
</a>
)
}
}
export default Chroma
```

Answer (score 5):

`event.target` is the simplest way to get this done.

But I notice that you didn't bind your mouse actions, you need to bind the `mouse` and `mouseout` like this:
`onMouseEnter={(event) => mouse(event)}`

Here is the working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n5jvrkxxwp

Answer (score 1):

Try using the info following in the event object:

```
const mouse = event => {
   const el = event.target // instead of getElementById('colorstext')
   .... your code
 }
```

Comment: Indeed this solved. Thanks a lot. Any idea if i could make it more simple ?